# String replacement without removing the inner part

Tags: javascript, regex

`` code.replace(/(id=".*?") (cx=".*?") (cy=".*?") (r=".*?") fill="currentcolor"/, ` id=${objectdata.id} fill="currentcolor"`) ``

Objective: changing the id in a tag that has fill="currentcolor" in it.

Problem: the above solution is deleting everything between id and fill.

Is there a working solution?

Comment: Why not do this using the DOM API instead of using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor problem: your current regex is missing quotes around `${objectdata.id}`

```
code.replace(/(id=".*?") (cx=".*?") (cy=".*?") (r=".*?") fill="currentcolor"/, ` id="${objectdata.id}" fill="currentcolor"`)
```

To preserve the values between them, you can use capture groups like this, where `$2` represents the substring matched by `(cx=".*?")`.

```
code.replace(/(id=".*?") (cx=".*?") (cy=".*?") (r=".*?") fill="currentcolor"/, ` id="${objectdata.id}" $2 $3 $4 fill="currentcolor"`)
```

However, if the value between them doesn't matter, you can also do it in this way, where everything except `id` belongs to `$2`

```
code.replace(/(id=".*?")(.*fill="currentcolor")/, ` id="${objectdata.id}"$2`)
```